# Javascript disable chrome notifications

Tags: javascript

I need a page with a button that when pressed disables or blocks all push notifications enabled on chrome. 
I tried this :

```
    let dnperm = document.getElementById('dnperm');


dnperm.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(!window.Notification){
        alert("Notification not supported!");
    }else{
        Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) {
            console.log(permission);
            if(permission === 'granted'){


permission = 'denied';
              alert("you succesd");
            }else if(permission === 'denied'){ alert("you fail");


 permission = 'granted';                    
            }
        })
    }
});
```

HTML :

```
<body>
<a href="" id="dnperm">block</a>
```

Comment: Hello Tou Mou, can you be more specific with your question? what does not work? is there more code that you have? Please give as much detail as possible to help SO help you. Thx.

Comment: IAmNerd2000  I need to block all chrome notifications if i click in a given html button like : <a href="" id="dnperm">block</a>

Comment: apparently , i failed to change the value of    Notification.permission

Answer (score 0):

You can`t change Notification.permission via browser API, it can be done only via native browser propt

Comment: Plz can you explain moe

Comment: Sure. Notifications API only provide interface for getting information about permissons butnot for setting them. You can call request dialog or add eventlistener for permission changes but not change it with javascript. For security purposes permissions can be changed only by clicking the button in dialog window with input device
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API

Comment: Rightly or wrongly, in their guide https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API they show an example of setting the permissions in JavaScript: `if(!('permission' in Notification)) { Notification.permission = permission; }`